# Sending Emails with mailKit obsolete warnings with MailboxAddress(String) constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mailkit

I have the following code that works fine sending emails, but I'm getting these warnings that say that I should label some of the methods Obsolete. I Looked at the docs on the [mailKit](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MailboxAddress.htm) website and it says that I should use a different constructor than `MailboxAddress(String)`. I get that, but am having troubles on how to implement the way they're asking, it seems simple but i think im missing a step. This is one of the ways that's recommend `MailboxAddress(String, String)` [new way of doing it](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MailboxAddress__ctor_3.htm).

Code as follows:

Controller

```
    public IActionResult RequestPassword()
    {
        var message = new Message(new string[]
        {
           "email@gmail.com"
           
        },
            "Test Email",
            "This is the content from out email."
        );

        _emailSender.SendEmail(message);

        return View();
    }
```

Message.cs

For this class the warning pops up on line `To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress(x)));`

```
public class Message
{
    public List<MailboxAddress> To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Message(IEnumerable<string> to, string subject, string content)
    {
        To = new List<MailboxAddress>();
       
        To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress(x)));                       
        Subject = subject;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

EmailSender class
For this class the warning pops up on line  `emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailConfig.From));`

```
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly EmailConfiguration _emailConfig; 
    public EmailSender(EmailConfiguration emailConfig)
    {
        _emailConfig = emailConfig; 
    }

    // This creates the Email and then sends it. 
    public void SendEmail(Message message)
    {
        var emailMessage = CreateEmailMessage(message);

        Send(emailMessage); 
    }

    // Creates Email Message
    private MimeMessage CreateEmailMessage(Message message)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailConfig.From));
        emailMessage.To.AddRange(message.To);
        emailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Text)
        {
            Text = message.Content
        }; 

        return emailMessage; 
    }

    // Sends the email
    private void Send(MimeMessage mailMessage)
    {
        using var client = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            client.Connect(_emailConfig.MailServer, _emailConfig.MailPort, false);
            client.Authenticate(_emailConfig.Username, _emailConfig.Password);
            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect(true);
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IEmailSender
{
    void SendEmail(Message message); 
}
```

If you want the StartUp.cs as well let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just the emailAddress and displayname that will show on the recipient.

```
var address = new MailboxAddress("Tonton", "tonton@example.com");
```

**Output**

[image]

**UPDATE**

If you want to add display name. You canhave something like this.

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public List<MailboxAddress> To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Message(IEnumerable<EmailAddress> to, string subject, string content)
    {
         To = new List<MailboxAddress>();
   
        To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress(x.DisplayName, x.Address)));                       
        Subject = subject;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I add that to the `To = new List<MailBoxAddress>();` list then in the Message class?

Comment: Since your example code snippet doesn't have display names, just do: `To.AddRange(to.Select(x => new MailboxAddress(string.Empty, x)));`

Comment: So what if I wanted to add the display name? what would I do then? I guess this is the part that im getting confused about the most. Thanks!

Comment: @whisk you can check the update on my answer. If it will help you about adding the display name.